# Eigenvalues and rank of $T(X)=AX$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$T:M_n(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$ defined by $T(X)=AX$ where $A$ is a fixed $n\times n$ matrix. I wish to find the characteristic polynomial and the rank of $T$. I looked at where $T$ sends the basis elements $E_{lm}$. I found that $T(E_{lm})=\sum\limits_k a_{kl}E_{km}$. From here I calculated the trace to be $n\operatorname{trace}(A)$. Finding the characteristic polynomial seemed to be difficult. I calculated for $n=2$. Letting $$A=
\bigg(\begin{matrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{matrix}\bigg)$$ I got $\chi_T(x)=(x-a)(x-d)\chi_A(x)$ where $\chi$ denotes the characteristic polynomial. However, I don't know how this generalizes to higher dimensions. The diagonal entries and characteristic roots of $A$ only account for $2n$ eigenvalues and not $n^2$. Also what about the rank of $T$? Does it only depend on the rank of $A$? By the looks of it $\operatorname{rank}T$ could also depend on how many diagonal entries of $A$ are $0$. Any help and/or reference would be appreciated.

Edit: I made an error; $\chi_T(x)$ is actually $\chi_A(x)^2$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A linear map $T$ in $M_n(K)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526061/a-linear-map-t-in-m-nk)

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, but no. They assume $A$ to be invertible, which is a very special case and gives the rank immediately. Also it says nothing about the eigenvalues.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600358/linear-operator-fx-axb) with $B=I$ may also be helpful.

Comment: It would improve your Question to format it in a way that highlights your problems(s).  You want some information about the linear map induced by multiplication by $A$, but it is visually difficult to find the specific information you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do the $2\times 2$ case. With respect to the basis
$$E_1=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0},\quad E_2=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0},\quad
E_3=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},\quad E_4=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}$$
the transformation $T$ has matrix
$$A'=\pmatrix{a&b&0&0\\c&d&0&0\\0&0&a&b\\0&0&c&d}.$$
It's apparent that the characteristic polynomial of $A'$ is the square
of that of $A$.

In the $n$-by-$n$ case we get $n$-th powers by a similar argument.

Comment: One could mention that "under the hood", we work with Kronecker product(s) $\otimes$, here  $vec(AX)=(I_2 \otimes A)vec(X)$